# Div with a specific width and height based on the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two Calendars side by side, and everything is looking fine using css grid. Awesome1 My issue now is that I want to replicate each  31 times simply by copy/pasting bellow on the html and somehow, using javascript fill the area but allowing only 7 divs per row and 5 rows filling the entire space of their container

Can someone suggest me how to solve it? I don't want to do it with grid, want it with javascript and generated based on that :) 7 x 5 boxes (Width x height) giving each blockCalendarBox the width and height dynamically?

Kind regards!

```css
.dashboardContentInnerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.8fr;
    grid-template-areas: "reportTitle reportTitle" "blockOne blockTwo";
}

.blockStyle {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
}

.blockTitleArea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.reportTitle { 
    grid-area: reportTitle; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
.blockOne { 
    grid-area: blockOne; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.color1 {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.blockCalendarWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 25px);
}

.blockCalendarBox {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    width:20px;  
    height:20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboardContentInnerWrapper">
            <div class="grid-container">
              <div class="reportTitle subtitle">Report / March 2020</div>
            
              <div class="blockOne blockStyle">
                <div class="blockTitleArea color1">FIRST CALENDAR</div>
                <div class="blockCalendarWrapper">
                    <div class="blockCalendarBox">1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="blockTwo blockStyle">
                <div class="blockTitleArea color1">SECOND CALENDAR</div>
                <div class="blockCalendarWrapper">
                    <div class="blockCalendarBox">1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solves your question.

```
.blockCalendarWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 25px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

if you want to use css on each box.

```
.blockCalendarBox {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    height: calc(100% / 5);
    text-align: center;
}
```

if you want to use javascript for the width and height,
you may get the with of the container and divide it by 7 for width.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks @Riku, but I was looking for a javascript solution :( at the end I found a css grid solution. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ didn't wanted to use css flex :(